# How to convert my Character Controller into Rigibody Movement in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I'm making a 3D Side-Scroll Platformer Game,

I have trouble with my character when it steps on the moving platform it will not come along on the platform. I want my character to stay on the moving platform so I think converting my Character Controller into Rigibody will help me,

I need help to give me ideas on how I can reuse my Character Controller Script in Rigibody. This is my code, how can I reuse this in Rigibody script?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 direction;
    public float speed = 8;

    public float jumpForce = 30;
    public float gravity = -20;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    public bool ableToMakeADoubleJump = true;

    public Animator animator;
    public Transform model;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (PlayerManager.gameOver)
        {
            //play death animation
            animator.SetTrigger("die");

            //disable the script    
            this.enabled = false;
        }

        float hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        direction.x = hInput * speed;

        animator.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(hInput));
        bool isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, 0.15f, groundLayer);
        animator.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            //Jump Codes
            ableToMakeADoubleJump = true;
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            direction.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            if (ableToMakeADoubleJump & Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                DoubleJump();
            }
        }
        if (hInput != 0)
        { 
            Quaternion newRoattion = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(hInput, 0, 0));
            model.rotation = newRoattion;
        } 

        //Move the player using the character controller
        controller.Move(direction * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void DoubleJump()
    {
        //Double Jump Codes
        animator.SetTrigger("doubleJump");
        direction.y = jumpForce;
        ableToMakeADoubleJump = false;
    }
    private void Jump()
    {
        direction.y = jumpForce;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend switching between the two. It would get tricky, and think about it, you are alternating between two very different things. One is movement and one is physics.

However, I would reccomend adding to your current script so that the player would move with the moving platform.

**There is a lot of stuff in this answer, so read the whole thing.**
Btw, when I talk about velocity, in your case it is `direction`.

Since it seems like you know how to code pretty well, I won’t write out the script, rather tell you some physics ideas to get you going in the right direction.

- The reason people can stand on a moving platform and not fall off is because of friction.
- If you are standing on a gameObject with enough friction (you could add a physics material the gameObject you stand on and change friction there. Note that physics materials only work with rigidbodies, but you might want to use it to just read the value)
- First of all, you are going to want to raycast down to obtain the object you are standing on. From there you can get the physics material from `hit.collider.sharedMaterial` (or any other `hit.` to obtain data about what object you are standing on.
- If they friction is too low, just make the character slip off, like it was before (I assume)
- If the friction is above a threshold, get the velocity from the object you are standing on. If it was a rigidbody, `hit.rigidbody.velocity`. If it is controlled by script, use `hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<scriptname>().velocityvariablename` **This part is continued later on**

This is not necessary but useful: You can think of this as grabbing on a rope. When you are grabbing on a slippery rope, and someone pulls it (Like tug of war), You won’t move because the rope will slide through your hands. If the rope had grip tape on it and someone pulled it, you would come with it because it has more friction. You can think of the platform the same way. **Now on to the more complex part:** When you grip a rope that is *stationary*, and someone pulls it, you come with it as its velocity changes. When the rope is already being pulled, so its velocity is not stationary and it is already something. You grab onto it and a similar thing happens. It is like you are becoming a part of that rope. Similar to how if you are running, the arms and legs and head is a part of you. If you lose grip, you are no longer a part of that body, like your arms falling off when running. In other words, you become part of the body when you attach yourself to it.

### Bottom line:

- Get the velocity of the platform and set `platformVel` to it, do not add that to velocity, rather do a *seperate* `controller.Move(platformVel)`.

A small customization:

- Vector3.Lerp the platformVel to 0, so it doesn’t change while on the platform, but gradually goes to (0,0,0) when you get off. This way, there is a little momentum maintained from standing on the platform.

Feel free to ask anything in the comments.